# Nativescript does not send CSRF token

Tags: java, angular, spring-security, csrf, nativescript

I have Spring Boot app with CSRF protection , it works fine with web(Angular 6) app since Angular  read and send XSRF-TOKEN automatically, But NativeScript  mobile app does not work . NativScript use same version of Angular 6. Do you know how I can fix or implement it?

Regards

Comment: Can you show how you actually send it?

Comment: In web app I didn't write any code, it just works, Since what I understand Angular reads cookies and send X-XSRF-TOKEN token with HttpClient, in NativeScript this does not works, I think because in mobile app we don't have cookies store. So probably there should be some custom code which will do that.